# Access website password protected with credentials in the http link

Tags: asp.net, http-authentication

I have a website "A" that is password protected with credentials stored in the DB and another website "B" with a single set of credentials stored in the web.config.
I would like to give access to site B to the users of site A after they login.
I know I should change the way the credentials are handled in site "B" and manage one set of shared credentials for both sites but I am wondering if there is a way to access site "B" from site "A" with a link without having to recode the access credentials logic of site"B". **Is it possible to pass the credentials within the link between two asp.net websites?**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use sign sign on credentials. You need to set machinekeys in the Config to be the same as a start. You should then be able to share auth tickets IIRC.

Have a read through this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx

Comment: Thank you. It looks quite interesting. I will study the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you ask cannot be done. Site B wants to check the user's credentials in order to provide him with the respective priveleges (this is the meaning of authentication). This is not possible if site B does not have access to the credentials repository of A.

On the other hand, if B has access to the A's users repositoty, you could just use it for users to authenticate directly in site B, building the respective functionality in site B. If A is using normal ASP.NET membership API, this should be fairly easy. Otherwise, you could implement your own membership API provider, using any kind of custom credentials repository. You could check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for ASP.NET Membership API.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks but as I said in my question, before I start coding the access logic of site B I like to investigate on alternatives. Otherwise I could simply rebuild the access on site B and share the same database of site A for credentials. The answer from ThelTGuy could be a viable alternative.